# Ping fails between two Linux systems via an intermediate linux

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I have a simple network with three Linux systems running CentOS 2.6.

Linux 1 (eth1: 192.138.14.1)----- (eth4:192.138.14.4) Linux 2 (eth2: 192.138.4.3)------(eth3: 192.138.4.2) Linux 3

I am unable to ping Linux 3 from Linux 1. What I am able to ping though is from Linux 1 to Linux 2 (eth2) and from Linux 3 to Linux 2 (eth4). This means from Linux 1, I am able to ping 192.138.4.3 but not 192.138.4.2.

Following is the output of route -n command in Linux1

```
Linux1# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.138.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.135.18.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth3
0.0.0.0         10.135.18.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

In Linux 2:

```
Linux2# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.138.15.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.138.14.0    192.138.14.4    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth4
192.138.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth4
192.138.4.0     192.138.4.3     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.135.18.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.138.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth2 
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1006   0        0 eth4
0.0.0.0         10.135.18.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

In Linux 3:

```
Linux3# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.138.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
10.135.18.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth3
0.0.0.0         10.135.18.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I have enabled IP forwarding in Linux 2

```
Linux2# vi /etc/sysctl.conf
# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Linux2#: sysctl -p 
sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
kernel.sysrq = 0
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
kernel.msgmnb = 65536
kernel.msgmax = 65536
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

The result of iptables -L in Linux 2:

```
Linux2# iptables -L  
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

To ping Linux3 from Linux 1, should I be adding specific rules for icmp in iptables ? If not, What am I missing ?

Comment: this is not programming question; try http://superuser.com instead.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk: Thanks, I understand. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039027/can-not-route-packets-from-one-interface-to-another> made me think I can get help from stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you're not on the same network. When linux1 tries to send a packet to 192.138.4.2 it looks at the routing table and sees that it should go to eth1. But it also sees that there is no GW, so it assumes that the packet is on the same network. So it sends an arp request for 192.138.4.2 but receives no answer.
You can verify my assumption by running "tcpdump -i eth1 arp" on linux 1 and see that you send a request and see no response. You can also just type 'arp' and see that you have an incomplete entry.
So basically your routing table should include a GW where packets are intended to be routed.
For example, instead of
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
It should be something like
192.138.4.0     192.138.14.4         255.255.255.0   UG     0      0        0 eth1
And same on the other side.

Comment: Yes. That works. But how was I able to ping 192.138.4.3 in the first place? It was still in a different network though local to the next device.

Comment: First of all you can return to the setup and check (listen for arps and understand what happened). Is it possible that the two interfaces are bridged? You can check that by running 'brctl show'. This would explain (becuase the arp packets are bridged between the interfaces).